# Why can't we access methods of non-public classes inside a java file?

Tags: java, class, methods

```
class Basics415 {   

    public static void main_hooo(){
        out.println("1234");    
    }

    void main_ho(){
    }       
}
```

In another file called Basics5.java:

```
public class Basics5 extends Basics415{   

    public static void main(){
        main_hooo();        // We are accessing a public method of Class Basics415 
        main_ho();  // BUT WE CANNOT ACCESS A NON PUBLIC METHOD FROM SAME CLASS 
    }       
}
```

Why can't we access `main_ho()` while we can access `main_hooo()` ?

Why basic415.main_ho or Basic415.main_hooo doesn't work inside the main method of Basics5?

Comment: Please take more time to format your post - it's got *huge* amounts of whitespace for no reason at the moment. Also, use spaces rather than tabs.

Comment: It would really help if you could post a *complete* example. What is `Basics1`? If it's irrelevant, remove it from `Basics415`. Where does `ClassCan_Be_Only_Public_or_Abstract_or_final` come into it?

Comment: Also, the call to `method_Inside_Basics4` doesn't compile, because you haven't declared it. This question is a mess at the moment.

Comment: There, now the question is much clearer... Now Siva, when you post a question it's recommended to post only the relevant code as well as the error message (compilation error - in your case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the methods are static and therefore the classes need are needed to access them.

```
Basics4.method_Inside_Basics4()
```

So, after you edited a bunch of code ...

```
public class Basics5 extends Basics415{   

    public static void main(){
        // accessing a static method in a static context.
        Basics415.main_hooo();

        // accessing an instance method in a static context.
        final Basics415 b = new Basics415();
        b.main_ho();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Okaym why basic415.main_ho or Basic415.main_hooo doesn't work inside the main method of Basics5?

Comment: ```main_ho``` is an instance method. You know the difference?

Comment: No. What is mean by instance method? Difference between what? So what are the other type of methods?

Comment: There are instance methods bound to instances of a class (```new Basics4()```) and static methods, which belong to the class itself (```Basics4.method_Inside_Basics4()```). That's partof the basic foundation of Java and its approach to OOP.

Answer (score 1):

Your trouble is that the **main** metod of class **Basics5** is a static method, static methods are defined  at class level and not at instance level, then you can't use method not static in a static method.

Answer (score -1):

You should access method_Inside_Basics4 method as Basics4.method_Inside_Basics4(). As Basics5 class extends Basics415 class, it inherits main_hooo method, which can be assessed from Basics5.